# My Headphone port doesn't work after today's update even though it shows on alsamixer and pavucontrol

Tags: sound, updates, headphones

Headphone port doesn't work after today's update even though it shows on alsamixer and pavucontrol. First time I have had this problem on Ubuntu 20.4.